# Remotely log out of and wipe chrome data

Tags: google-chrome, security

For security reasons I need to log out of a device that I was previously logged into on Google Chrome (not just logged into Gmail, Drive, etc. but logged in with my Chrome profile).

There are some old threads on this but the solutions there appear to no longer work. What I have tried:

1. Changing my Google account password. After testing this, this oddly does not explicitly log out of my google account on other devices.
2. Furthermore, even if explicitly force a sign out on laptop A via laptop B, when I check laptop A: Sure, I am signed out of Gmail, Drive, etc, and my Chrome sync has paused. But all of the Chrome data (passwords, bookmarks, etc.) remain. It seems I am still "logged in" to my Google Chrome profile.

How can I remotely make sure the aforementioned Chrome data is wiped from the device and I am logged out from Chrome?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: You failed to indicate the operating system running on the device  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Can we assume you do not have physical access to this machine you are logged in to? It's implied, but you never actually stated this. Also, are you logged into Chrome in a session of your own account, or did you sign in to the Chrome browser in someone else's user session on that computer?

Comment: I dont think you can wipe local data but this should disable access on all connected devices:  https://www.wikihow.com/Sign-Out-of-Your-Google-Account-on-All-Devices-at-Once